# Иконка сайта меняется

Tags: дефект, статус-не-воспроизводится, дизайн

Как правило иконка сайта синяя. Но порой вместо неё вижу иконку как на en SO.

Открыл страницу вопросов и открыл [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474097/alarmmanager-%D0%B8-service-or-receiver) вопрос. Почему-то иконка на страницу вопроса как на en SO.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Последняя версия Firefox.

Comment: Это у вас браузер что-то не так кеширует. Сделайте Ctrl+F5

Comment: @LEQADA оно периодически так делает. С разными страницами сайта.

Comment: На Chrome не воспроизводится. Когда такое бывает, посмотрите ресурсы страницы. Проверьте адрес favicon

Comment: FF, OSX, не воспроизводится. Может, кеш почистить?

Comment: @NickVolynkin кеш чистил, явно не в этом дело.

Comment: @LEQADA адрес http://cdn.sstatic.net/ru/img/favicon.ico?v=b95a7516ec95

Comment: все еще воспроизводится?

Comment: @NickVolynkin ага, периодически

Comment: @Suvitruf, прошу прощения, почему-то не пришло уведомление. Только сейчас заметил. А этот адрес у вас что показывает?

Comment: @LEQADA на мете иконка всегда серая. Проблема именно на основном сайте

Comment: @Suvitruf, я про ту, что вы опубликовали комментариями выше.

Comment: @LEQADA синяя там.

Comment: @Suvitruf, выходит, что проблема в вашем браузере, так? )

Comment: @LEQADA если такое только у меня, то, видимо, да.

Comment: @Suvitruf,  если исходный код страницы показывает ссылку, которая ведёт на синий логотип, когда в качестве фавикона вы видите оранжевый, то с очень большой вероятностью это именно браузер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox загружает вкладки только при переходе на них. Вполне возможно, что для вкладок, которые были открывались ещё при старой иконке, она закешировалось и показывается. Вероятно, иконка изменится при обновлении (или при полном обновлении) страницы.